# Security concerns regarding validation of a signed XML document

Tags: xml, certificate, saml-2.0

So, I have this signed XML document. In this case, a SAML2 response. I want to verify that this XML document has not been tampered with somehow. If I understand it correctly, the way to do this is to check the signature of the signed document against the public key with which it was signed.

I know how to check the signature, so that's not the issue. The question I have is regarding what is actually verified when I check the signature.

I have an example XML which includes the certificate that was used to sign the XML. If I understand it correctly I can extract the public key of the certificate from the XML, and use the extracted key to verify the XML has not been tampered with. This seems to work fine when I try.

My problem with this is, does this not just verify that the XML validates against its own included certificate? Or am I missing something? What if somebody replaced the entire response-XML with their own, signed, response. I'm assuming that the fake response would validate just fine against its own included certificate, just as well as the legitimate response would validate against its own included certificate?

Wouldn't you have to validate the signed XML against a known certificate (e.g installed in the local certificate store) to both ensure that the response wasn't tampered with, and came from the expected source?

Comment: There is a private key in the certificate. The xml sent only contains the public part of the key so somebody cannot tamper the with the transmitter message.  The certificate should never be sent with the actual message so somebody  can't change both the certificate and message.

Comment: @jdweng I'm not sure why the certificate is included in the signed Xml, but I'm sure there are reasons to do it. Its not anything I can control from my side.

Comment: The certificate should only be included in the signed xml, when the xml is kept trusted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My problem with this is, does this not just verify that the XML validates against its own included certificate?

Yep, you are correct.

> Wouldn't you have to validate the signed XML against a known certificate?

For both the raw public key and the embedded certificate case it's important to verify that the key is acceptable. Ideally, you should accept (or reject) the key before checking the signature.

For a raw public key "acceptable" probably means "was established via a side-channel ahead of time". e.g. the other party told you the public key (or keys) they will use, and you make sure you're seeing one of them.

For certificates, you can either use the shared-ahead-of-time strategy, or trust a private CA and check that the private CA issued the certificate (assuming you trust everyone who can get a cert from that CA equally), or some other (or combinations of) characteristics-based decision.

For more information, see [SignedXml - Security considerations about the KeyInfo element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedxml?view=netframework-4.8#security-considerations-about-the-keyinfo-element)
 and [SignedXml - Security considerations about the X509Data element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedxml?view=netframework-4.8#security-considerations-about-the-x509data-element)

Comment: Thank you. I was worried I had misunderstood something. 
The plan I was considering was to get the signing certificate from the identity provider and install it to the certificate store. I will then use the installed certificate to validate the signed Xml.